# Define custom attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am dynamically generating XSLT string for my project. In the XSLT I want to append a datatype attribute along with each element.The generated XSLT is given below. But while validating XSLT an error is giving. How to add that datatype attribute in the XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                      
     
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Envelops>
      
      <order>
      
      <id datatype="Number">3</id datatype="Number">
      </order>
    </Envelops>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: try `<id datatype="Number">3</id>`

Comment: *"dynamically generating XSLT string'* Huh? Anyway, it seems you're trying to put together an XSLT stylesheet by trial and error. Your chances of succeeding in that are very low.

Comment: @michael.hor257k may be you are thinking it trial and error method but for the last 7 years, we are successfully doing that. This is the new requirement of adding datatype as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT needs to be well-formed XML. As such, you can't put attributes in an end tag. Change `<id datatype="Number">3</id datatype="Number">` to `<id datatype="Number">3</id>`